# How can I split columns to their own row when comma-separated in column using PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

As the title suggests, I need to split out some columns that comma-separated. I also want to perform a carthesian product of the columns for each line.

Let's say the source data looks like this:

| Id | Name | Codes_A | Codes_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | George | 1,2 | 3,4 |
| 2 | Mary | 5,6 | 7,8 |

I would like the outcome to look something like below, where all the values in the comma-separated columns are combined to each possible outcome.

| Id | Name | Codes_A | Codes_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | George | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | George | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | George | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | George | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | Mary | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | Mary | 5 | 8 |
| 2 | Mary | 6 | 7 |
| 2 | Mary | 6 | 8 |

Comment: How are you getting last 2 rows of `George` and last 3 rows of `Mary`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.o/Cartesian_productrg/wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the cartesian product of Codes_A & Codes_B values.
I'm assuming this is what you actually need.

**Demo setup**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'George','1,2','3,4'),(2,'Mary','5,6','7,8')],['Id','Name','Codes_A','Codes_B'])

df.show()

+---+------+-------+-------+
| Id|  Name|Codes_A|Codes_B|
+---+------+-------+-------+
|  1|George|    1,2|    3,4|
|  2|  Mary|    5,6|    7,8|
+---+------+-------+-------+
```

**Solution**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_result = (df
             .withColumn('Codes_A', F.explode(F.split('Codes_A',',')))
             .withColumn('Codes_B', F.explode(F.split('Codes_B',',')))
            )

df_result.show()

+---+------+-------+-------+
| Id|  Name|Codes_A|Codes_B|
+---+------+-------+-------+
|  1|George|      1|      3|
|  1|George|      1|      4|
|  1|George|      2|      3|
|  1|George|      2|      4|
|  2|  Mary|      5|      7|
|  2|  Mary|      5|      8|
|  2|  Mary|      6|      7|
|  2|  Mary|      6|      8|
+---+------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you David. I made a mistake in the output example. I edited so it is according to the proper product. This was exactly what I needed.